# Javascript new object field not saved

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using node.js and mongoose to get some data based on a query. Mongoose function *findOne* returns a promise which gives me a javascript object. I want to add a new field to that object and give it a value then apply the stringify function. If I print the string I've got, the new field I added will not be printed even though I can access it through the object.

```
model.findOne({},function (err, names) {})
         .then(function(data){
                    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
                    data['status'] = 200;
                    data['message'] = 'OK';
                    response.write(JSON.stringify(data));
                    response.end();
                },
                function(err) {
                    response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
                    var execError = '{"status":500,"message":"'+ err.toString() +'"}';
                    response.write(execError);
                    response.end();
                }
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are after the **[`lean()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean)** method, this allows you to return a plain JavaScript version of the result document in the query chain. It works with Mongoose not creating the full model instance and you then get the full JavaScript object that you can modify. Thus change your query chain to:

```
var promise = model.findOne().lean();
promise.then(function(data){
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        data['status'] = 200;
        data['message'] = 'OK';
        response.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        response.end();
    },
    function(err) {
        response.writeHead(500, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
        var execError = '{"status":500,"message":"'+ err.toString() +'"}';
        response.write(execError);
        response.end();
    }
);
```